# How to Link my flutter app to device contact

Tags: android, flutter

If you have installed Skype or WhatsApp you will find those apps are linked in the device contacts.[image]

I want to do this to my flutter app. I want my app to be linked like this. If the contact has an account in my app. In my device contacts, my app will be linked like this one. Anyone know how to do that!

Comment: check this:https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/flutter_contact

Comment: I believe this is associated with Device's Account Manager. Check [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/accountmanager) for possible solution.